# How to adapt Tkinter Sqlite to Mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I have a problem. I would like to adapt this code so that it works only with a mysql database. I have tried but could not. I find it frustrating. You could help me by indicating what changes to make. Thank you very much.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

import sqlite3

class Product:
# connection dir property
db_name = 'database.db'

def __init__(self, window):
    # Initializations 
    self.wind = window
    self.wind.title('Products Application')
    
    # Table
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height = 10, columns = 2)
    self.tree.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
    self.tree.heading('#0', text = 'Name', anchor = CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#1', text = 'Price', anchor = CENTER)

     # Filling the Rows
    self.get_products()

# Function to Execute Database Querys
def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return result

# Get Products from Database
def get_products(self):
    # cleaning Table 
    records = self.tree.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree.delete(element)
    # getting data
    query = 'SELECT * FROM product'
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)
    # filling data
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[1], values = row[2])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    application = Product(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What problem are you having in adapting it to mysql? It doesn't look like you've even tried. Also, please take a moment to fix the indentation problem in the posted code.

Comment: You can find many resources on how to use MySQL in Python when you search on the internet, for example in [`w3schools`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp).

Comment: I have tried, I have several drafts. I have rummaged through various Mysql Tkinter blogs. And still nothing.

Comment: What problem you came across when you want to migrate to MySQL actually?